# Getting FB is not defined Error

Tags: javascript, facebook

I tried many solutions discussed but still having the FB is not defined error. The basic idea is to share a image on my facebook wall on click of facebook icon. Below is my code which is in .js file.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
appId      : '7895784589567515249',
xfbml      : true,
version    : 'v2.3',
status     : true
});
};

(function(d, s, id){
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function shareOnFb(id,route,imageUrl,description,title,type) {
var caption;
var protocol = window.location.protocol;
var hostname = window.location.host;
var share_url = protocol+"//"+hostname+"/"+route;
var share_image = imageUrl;
if(type == "news") {
    caption="News @ testExample";
    share_image = imageUrl;
} else if(type == "story") {
    caption="Read this book";
}else {
    caption= "View this Charac";
}
FB.ui({
method: 'feed',
link: share_url,
caption: caption,
description:description,
picture:share_image,
name:title
}, function(response){
if(response) {
if(response.post_id) {
callfunction(id,type,"facebook");   
}
else {
$('.errorMessage').html("Could Not share on facebook");
$("#errorMsg_popup").modal();
}
}
else {
$('.errorMessage').html("Could Not share on facebook");
$("#errorMsg_popup").modal();
}
});
}
```

Below is the code snippet from which I am making call to above function on click of a facebook icon.

```
<img src="{{../cdn_url}}/images/FB_Icon.png" onclick="shareOnFb({{this._id}},'users/myCharacters/{{this._id}}/posterView','{{this.char_thumbnail_url}}','','{{this.fb_name}}','characters')">
```

Comment: Try loading the SDK before calling FB.init.

Comment: @sideroxylon How but?

Comment: are you trying to use this code without a server?

Comment: @luschn No. I am running nodeJS server..

Comment: ok, can we get a test link?

Comment: Sorry..can't give that link...

Comment: well, in that case you have to debug on your own. make sure the js sdk is loaded before using it.

Comment: Set the definition of your function inside the fbAsyncInit method. More that likely your ShareOnFB function is getting loaded before init is finished.